# Expand box in all directions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, position

I have the following structure:

[image]

My goal is when the user mouseover the boxes, they should expand and go over the others without breaking the UI. So basically the box should expand 20px in every directive, while every other element stays on the same place. Note that I dont know the exact size of the boxes, because they're responsible.

I'm positioning the boxes like this:

```
#holder {
    width: 250px;
    background-color: #FFCCCC;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 15px;
}

.box {
    width: 45%;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px grey solid;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.box:nth-child(odd) {
    float: right;
}
```

With the HTML below:

```
<div id="holder">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

And I'm handling the events using jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".box").mouseenter(function(){
      var _this = $(this);
      var newWidth = parseInt(_this.css("width")) + 40,
          newHeight = parseInt(_this.css("height")) + 40;

    _this.
        css("z-index", 99).
        animate({
            width: newWidth + "px",
            height: newHeight + "px",
            marginTop: "-20px",
            marginLeft: "-20px"
        }, 1000);
});

 $(".box").mouseleave(function(){
      var _this = $(this);
      var newWidth = parseInt(_this.css("width")) - 40,
          newHeight = parseInt(_this.css("height")) - 40;

    _this.
    css("z-index", 1).
    animate({
        width: newWidth + "px",
        height: newHeight + "px",
        marginTop: "0px",
        marginLeft: "0px"
    }, 1000);
});
});
```

And here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3T89h/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way I can think of is absolute positioning (although there is probably is a much neater way).

You'd need to apply

```
position:absolute;
```

to each box, give it a fixed height/width (percentages wouldn't really work) and position it manually, for example

http://jsfiddle.net/3T89h/1/

**Edit:**

If your boxes need to be responsive, have undetermined heights & widths, then it's still possible to do this with a similar method.

You can use your original boxes as a container, with

```
position:relative;
```

and then within them keep your actual content which'll be absolutely positioned, here's an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/3T89h/2/

So essentially you now have boxes acting as a responsive wrapper, which contain an inner box with the desired effect, that matches the wrapper's dimensions. The design can then be changed dramatically, but the javascript effect you wanted will not be altered, eg: http://jsfiddle.net/3T89h/3/

Comment: Forgot to add that boxes are responsible and I don't know their size or position.

Comment: @Deepsy Ah, then it gets more tricky! But is still do-able via this method.

Comment: I got it working somehow :) Sorry for the late answer, but I forgot about marking this question as solved. Thanks.